# Got stuck with this $L^2(-1, 1)$ optimization problem. Any ideas where it comes from?

Tags: reference-request, optimization, proof-verification, convex-optimization

#### Statement

Let $u(x) \in L^2(-1, 1)$. Solve the following optimization problem:

$$
\begin{cases}
J(u) = 4 \int_{-1}^{1} \sqrt{|x| (1 - |x|)} u(x) dx + \left(\int_{-1}^1 \sin(3\pi x) u(x) dx\right)^2 \rightarrow \inf_{u} \\
3\sqrt{3}\left(\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt{|x|(1 - |x|)} u(x) dx\right)^2 + \int_{-1}^{1}\sin(3\pi x) u(x )dx \leq 0
\end{cases}
$$

#### Attempted solution

Let's introduce these two functions: $f(x) = \sqrt{|x|(1 - |x|)}$ and $g(x) = \sin(3\pi x)$. Then the problem can be rewritten as:
$$
\begin{cases}
J(u) = 4 \left<f, u\right> + \left<g, u\right>^2 \\
3\sqrt{3} \left<f, u\right>^2 + \left<g, u\right> \leq 0
\end{cases}
$$

Any function $u \in L^2(-1, 1)$ is in the domain of both $J(u)$ and the inequality. Let's use second-order convexity criterion:

$$
\begin{align}
\nabla_u J(u) &= 4f + 2 g\left<g, u\right> \\
\nabla_u^{2}J(u) &= 2g^2(x)
\end{align}
$$

Since $\forall h \in L^2(-1, 1)$ we have $\left<2g^2h, h\right> = 2\int_{-1} ^ {1}g^2(x)h^2(x) dx \geq 0$ then we conclude that $J(u)$ is convex. We use the same approach to show the inequality is convex, which results in the problem being convex.

Now I am going to say that function

$$
u(x) =
\begin{cases}
1, x \in [0, 1] \\
-1, x \in [-1, 0)
\end{cases}
$$

is the one to satisfy [Slaiter's condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slater%27s_condition). This means that the [KKT conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) are not only necessary but sufficient conditions of extrema for this problem. Let's write KKT conditions:

$$
\begin{cases}
4f + 2g\left<g, u\right> + \lambda_1 \left(6\sqrt{3}f\left<f, u\right> + g\right) = 0, \\
3\sqrt{3} \left<f, u\right>^2 + \left<g, u\right> \leq 0, \\
\lambda_1 \left(3\sqrt{3} \left<f, u\right>^2 + \left<g, u\right>\right) = 0, \\
\lambda_1 \geq 0
\end{cases}
$$

This system is a disaster: I can't solve it. Perhaphs, you can? Have I made a mistake somewhere? Maybe you know the book from which this problem was taken? Are there any good books with solved examples of optimization problems of this level? (Stephen Boyd is really good but I don't believe there are such problems there)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Your problem is addressed in functional analysis and is a constrained calculus of variations problem. I would form the Lagrangian and get rid of the constraint, and then would try to derive the Lagrange-Euler formula for the problem.

Comment: I can't say I completely understand your suggestion, but here is a few obvious problems. The Euler-Lagrange equation for this problem will be $\frac{\partial J(u)}{\partial u} - \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial J(u)}{\partial u'} = 0$. Since $J(u)$ doesn't depend on $u'$, then it boils down to $\frac{\partial J(u)}{\partial u} = 0$, which in turn is simply the necessary condition of extrema.

Comment: btw, we've noticed that $\nabla_u J(u) = 4f + 2g\langle g,u \rangle$ never equals to $0$. Is this enough to say that extrema of this problem is attained at the boundary?

Comment: Regardless of the (more) general solution of the system, I think you are right! It seems like any function $u(x)$ such that $u(-x)=-u(x)$ results in an objective of zero (It might be just an oversight and I may be wrong), I tried to come up with a solution that gives an smaller (i.e. negative) objective, but I could find any thing.

Comment: "btw, we've noticed that ...", basically for your suggested $u(x)$ we have $\nabla_u J(u)=4f$ right? then, I'm having a hard time to figure out how the first line of the KKT conditions could hold? (i.e. $4f + 2g\left<g, u\right> + \lambda_1 \left(6\sqrt{3}f\left<f, u\right> + g\right) = 0 ~~~\Rightarrow~~ 4f + \lambda_1 g = 0$, because the dot-products are zero), please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I believe you are wrong: it is not obvoius to me that $J(u) = 0$ if $u(-x) = -u(x)$. I also believe you misunderstand me: $\nabla_u J(u)$ is never $0$ because of the following: $\langle g, u\rangle$ is a constant for any $u(x)$. Now, there is no such *constant* that can be multiplied by $2g$ to get $4f$ because these functions aren't linearly dependent. You can just plot $f = \sqrt{|x|(1 - |x|)}$ and $g = \sin(3\pi x)$ and see that.

Comment: Yeah, I had said that maybe I'm wrong, I think just by the symmetry that is in your objective and the constraint, you can conclude that  your suggestion for $u$ is a solution.

Comment: "I also believe you misunderstand me ... ", I was not misunderstood, and don't know why you believe so. Your $f$ and $g$ can be seen infinite dimensional vectors, and that is clear that for your functions,  $\alpha f+\beta g\neq 0$ unless $\alpha=\beta=0$.